# Getting file details and not printing directory help

Tags: java, file

I am trying to make a program which will print all files in my current directory (but not the directories), and at the moment what I have is printing all files and directories in my home directory. How can I change this ?

My code at the moment :

```
File[] fileList = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")).listFiles();
```

Also, how can I print the details of these files as well ? I would like the file size, permissions, anything I can get, so as to make my program the equivalent to an ls -a in unix.

Can someone please help me with this as I cannot find the pertinent Java functions anywhere?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Loop the array and print only those which have `isFile()` `true` (or `isDirectory()` `false`). The current directory is simpyl `new File("")`

All details you can obtain by calling the respective methods, like `canRead()`, `canWrite()`, `length()`, etc. Check [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) for more

Comment: It's still printing everything in my home directory though, rather than the current directory. I've tried to change this myself but keep getting the syntax wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FileFilter to get rid of dirs

```
File[] files = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")).listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return !file.isDirectory();
    }
});
```

You can get the size of file with `file.length()`

Answer (score 0):

Get the current directory by initializing a file object for it and then using the listFiles() method from that object.  Then loop over the resulting list and test each file with the [File.isFile()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29) method:

```
File cwd = new File(".");
File[] fileList = cwd.listFiles()
for (File aFile : fileList) {
    if (aFile.isFile()) {
        System.out.println(aFile);
    }
}
```

You can use the [canExecute()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29), [canRead()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canRead%28%29), and [canWrite()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canWrite%28%29) methods to find out if your program can do those things.  As noted in another answer, [length()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29) will give you the size.

Comment: Does length not return the length of the absolute path to the file rather than its size ?

Comment: @Charles Sheen : `length()` returns the size of the file in bytes. Not the length of filepath string.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the files by using a `FileFilter`, like so:

```
  File dir = new File("/path/to/directory");

  FileFilter fileFilter = new FileFilter() {
      public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isFile();
      }
    };

  File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
  for (File file : files) {
    System.out.println("File: " + file);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense.

You ask in your coment to Bozho to print a list of files in the current directory, but  specifically asks for a list of files in "user.home", which is your home directory.

If you don't want to list the files in your home directory, change your code to ask for files from somewhere else.

Comment: That's what I am asking for the help with.

Comment: I'm still confused. Don't use "user.home"; did you try just "." or "./" instead?